# cat: /proc/apci/wakeup: No such file or directory

Tags: command-line, suspend, directory

I was setting my laptop to now wake by pressing keyboard on moving the mouse, so I created simple script to disable all except PWRB:

```
for d in `cat /proc/apci/wakeup |grep enabled|grep -v PWRB|cut -b -4`; do echo $d >/proc/acpi/wakeup ; done
```

but when I run it, it says:

```
cat: /proc/apci/wakeup: No such file or directory
```

but when I manually run `cat /proc/acpi/wakeup` it normally shows content of `wakeup`.

What am I missing?

Please say everything simply, I am a nooby user. Thank you very much.

Comment: You have a typo in your script - your script says `apci` when it should say `acpi`

Comment: Yeah, you are right, thank you very much, I have totally overlooked it.

Comment: I cannot mark your answer as solution, sorry codlord :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simplify your script.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

while read -r a _ b _; do
    [[ $a != PWRB \
    && $b == \*enabled ]] && echo $a
done < /proc/acpi/wakeup > /proc/acpi/wakeup
```

Comment: Ok, thank you, I will try it.